# Is it possible to make yellow background surround only "This is Main website" word?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
* { 
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
    
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1> This is Main website </h1>
```

Is it possible to make the yellow color only surround the text instead of the whole line?

Comment: `display:inline` works.

Answer (score 0):

You just change the property `display: block` to `display: inline-block` and it would work the way you want it to. Try this code.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span> This is Main website </span> </h1>
```

Comment: But now it doesn't move to the center of my page.

Comment: in that case, you can add a <span> element to wrap your text and try the css styles i have edited in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `span` tag for the text which has `display: inline-block` (this also allows you to keep the text centered and have the border spanning the whole width)

You can use `padding` settings to extend the yellow area a bit if you want

```css
* {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span> This is Main website </span> </h1>
```